# The Change Event Jquery?

Tags: jquery, onchange

could somebody tell me what's wrong with the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select name="target">
            <option value="item1">item1</option>
            <option value="item2">item2</option>
            <option value="item3">item3</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
<script>
    $(".target").change(function () {
        alert("Handler for .change() called.");
    });
</script>
```

Nothing alert on item change!!? Am I missing something
Thanks.

Comment: jQuery selectors use the css selector syntax. In a stylesheet, how would you select that element? That same selector is the one you would use in jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put an `id` on your `select` element and use that in the selector instead:

Names are for form submission, IDs should be used for DOM traversal:

```js
$('#target').on('change', function() {
  alert('changed to ' + this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="target" id="target">
  <option value="item1">item1</option>
  <option value="item2">item2</option>
  <option value="item3">item3</option>
</select>
```

NB: `.on('change', ...)` rather than `.change(...)` will make it easier to find your event registrations in your code.

Comment: @Riad in which case you have some other issue - perhaps not loading jQuery properly.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you are attaching the event handler to all elements with the **class** `target`, whereas the element you *want* to target has the **name** target.

You need to use an attribute selector:

```
$("select[name=target]").change(function () {
    alert("Handler for .change() called.");
});
```

***Or***, apply a matching class to your element:

```
<select name="target" class="target">
    <option value="item1">item1</option>
    <option value="item2">item2</option>
    <option value="item3">item3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: but better would be to put an `id` or `class` on the element instead.  Names are for form submission, IDs for DOM traversal.

Comment: dunno - wasn't me, although personally I think an ID is more appropriate than a class in the circumstances.

Comment: works for me (with jQuery loaded, of course!) - http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/dtposwqb/

Comment: I am referencing the library, but it seems that something block the on change event